# Projective Representations of $SO(2)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

For $SO(3)$ and $SO^+(3,1)$, their [projective representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) take one of two possible forms
\begin{equation}
D(\Lambda_1)D(\Lambda_1) = \pm D(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)
\end{equation}

As far as I know, only these two forms are possible because both $SO(3)$ and $SO(3,1)$ have their fundamental group as $\mathbb{Z_2}$.

So, for the group $SO(2)\cong U(1)$, whose fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$, what all forms can its projective representations take?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Projective reps of $U(1)$ are linear reps of its universal covering group. For $U(1)$, the universal covering group is $\mathbb R$. It's an infinite-to-one covering, unlike the $SO(3)$ case (2-to-1). $U(1)\simeq\mathbb R/\pi_1(S^1)= \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. Representations of $U(1)$ are of the form $\theta\rightarrow e^{i\alpha \theta}$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb Z$ such that $e^{2\pi i\alpha}=1$. But if you allow $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, you get projective representations as well.